# Access atribute of every object in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following mwe:

```
import pandas as pd
from decimal import *
from datetime import date

d1={'Date':date(2016,10,24),'Value':Decimal(20)}
d2={'Date':date(2016,10,25),'Value':Decimal(10)}
d3={'Date':date(2016,9,25),'Value':Decimal(50)}
d4={'Date':date(2016,9,24),'Value':Decimal(5)}

df=pd.DataFrame([d1,d2,d3,d4])
```

I'm able to access the `month`attribute of a single date the following way:

```
df.Date[0].month
Out[22]: 10
```

However `df.Date.month` does not return a vector containing all the months as I would expect. Instead it throws me an error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'

Is there a nice way to accomplish this without having to iterate over the dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need first convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.month)
0    10
1    10
2     9
3     9
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Another slowier solution with `apply`:

```
print (df.Date.apply(lambda x: x.month))
0    10
1    10
2     9
3     9
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

**Timings**:

```
#[40000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [292]: %timeit (df.Date.apply(lambda x: x.month))
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop

In [293]: %timeit (pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.month)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.44 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, that was spot on! I was not aware of the difference between `type(df.Date[0])
Out[39]: datetime.date` and `type(pd.to_datetime(df.Date)[0])
Out[41]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp`